# Pretty print json not working in python 3.7?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have this code in my python file:

```
data_new = '''{{"homeMobileCountryCode": {0}, "homeMobileNetworkCode": {1}, 
"cellTowers":[{{"cellId": {2}, 
"locationAreaCode": {3}, "mobileCountryCode": {4}, "mobileNetworkCode": 
{5}}}]}}'''

newdata = data_new.format(mcc, mnc, cid, lac, mcc, mnc)
data_json = json.dumps(newdata, indent=4)
print(data_json)
```

However instead of giving me something like this:

```
{ 
  "homeMobileCountryCode": 12, 
  "homeMobileNetworkCode": 12, 
  "cellTowers": [ 
  { 
   "cellId": 12, 
   "locationAreaCode": 12, 
   "mobileCountryCode": 12, 
   "mobileNetworkCode": 12
  } 
 ] 
}
```

It gave me this instead:

```
{\"homeMobileCountryCode\": 32, \"homeMobileNetworkCode\": 45, \"cellTowers\":[{\"cellId\": 324, \n    \"locationAreaCode\": 324, \"mobileCountryCode\": 32, \"mobileNetworkCode\": 45}]}
```

I tried doing this in the terminal it gives me the same output. Where should I go from here?

Comment: You are serializing a `str` object to json, so you get a JSON String (which happens to be valid JSON), but it's pretty print representation is a single line (as it should be). You need to serialize that python data structure, not a string representation of it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. If you want to create a JSON string, start with a Python datastructure including your variables. Apart from anything else, you won't need to worry about escaping characters.

```
data_new = {
    "homeMobileCountryCode": mcc,
    "homeMobileNetworkCode": mnc,
    "cellTowers": [
         {"cellId": cid, "locationAreaCode": lac, "mobileCountryCode": mcc, "mobileNetworkCode": mnc}
    ]
}
data_json = json.dumps(data_new, indent=4)
```